# calculate deviations from mean scaled by covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matlab

I would like to calulate the following:

$y_{i} = S^{-1/2}(x_{i}-\bar{x})$

where, $\bar{x}$ and $S$ are the sample mean and the sample covariance matrix of the initial sample $(x_{1}; ... ; x_{n})$.

**First question:** Is this the same as the following:

$Y = \Sigma^{-1/2}(X-\mu )$

where $E(X)=\mu $ and $D(X)=\Sigma $ (Covariance Matrix)

I used the following matlab code to implement the first calculation.

```
[m, n] = size(X);
S = cov(X);

%%  Y
Y = zeros(size(X,2));
for j=1:n
    % yi = S^(-1/2)*(xi-x.mean)
    Y(:,j) = (chol(S)')^(-1)*(X(1,:)'-mean(X(:,1)));
end
```

**Second Question:** What is the intuition behind the calculation? It has zero mean, but what is the effect of the negative square root of the covariance?

Comment: You got the dimensions wrong.  When you using S = cov(X), you're saying each row of matrix X is a sample.  size(X,1) is the number of samples.  If $\mathbf{X}$ is a $K$ dimensional random variable, and there are N samples, then the matrix $X$ is NxK.

Comment: @Guangliang thanks. I think I got the dimension in my matlab code correct now. Any Intuition what Y is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that they are usually not the same.  Because the sample mean/covariance are usually different from the 'true' mean/covariance of the distribution. But when the 'true' parameters are not available, then the sample parameters are usually pretty good approximate.

As for your 'intuition' question, this procedure makes the sample with zero mean and uncorrelated.  It is quite useful in numerical computation.

One advice for your matlab/octave code, to have the best performance, avoid loops.  If a loop is unavoidable, avoid unnecessary repeated calculation in the loop.  In your particular case, the code can be replaced with this one line Matlab/Octave code:

```
Y = (X-repmat(mean(X),size(X,1),1))*inv(chol(S));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two small follow up questions. First, in your code you are postmultiplying not pre with inv(chol(S)). Is this identical to pre multiplying? Second, imagine the sample statistics would be identical to true statistics. Would this mean that calculating Y=Σ^(−1/2)*(X−μ)  is identical to yi=S^(−1/2)*(xi−x¯).

Comment: Actually, I don't think your code is a correct implementation of your math. The result of your $Y$ is $n\times n$, not $m\times n$.  On your second question, the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: As for 'pre-multiplying' vs. 'post-multiplying', please note that $x'*inv(chol(S)) = inv(chol(S))'*x$.